# hide block of code from showing on certain pages

Tags: conditional-tags

Just to warn you, I am a complete PHP novice!

I have one sidebar for all pages, however I would like to display certain elements on this sidebar for certain pages.

I know there are a few widget plugins, however I am not using widgets, I am just coding in the sidebar.php file.

I am aware I can do this...

```
<?php if( is_page('37') ):?>
SHOW STUFF
<?php endif;?>
```

... for showing the content if on that page, but what is the opposite of this? So that 'SHOW STUFF' does not show if we are on page 37?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can use:

```
<?php if( !is_page('37') ):?>
SHOW STUFF
<?php endif;?>
```

P.S. ! (not parameter)

Good tutorial - http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/php-conditional-statements/